# How to draw a black border around the image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, crop, grayscale, noise-reduction

How can I crop the image such that it will only contain the leaf and not have the noise part? [image]

Comment: Do you have the image processing toolbox? Which MATLAB version are you using? There seems to be a discrepancy between the title of the topic and what you're asking. Do you want to have an image with a smaller size, or will the same size, only keeping the leaf, will do? Is the object you want to keep always the largest?

Answer (score 4):

If you have the [Image Processing Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/), you can do something like this:

- [Morphologically open](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imopen.html) the image (to remove salt and pepper noise).
- Convert the image to binary.
- Detect the largest contiguous area (presumably the object-of-interest).
- Set all other pixels to an "ignored value" (in this case, `255`).
- "Crop" the original image by means of indexing the bounding box.

```
function out = q42849445
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTtqz.jpg');
bw = ~imopen(logical(img),strel('disk',10));
stats = regionprops(bw,'Area','SubarrayIdx');
[~,I] = max([stats.Area]);
for ind = setdiff(1:numel(stats),I)
  img(stats(ind).SubarrayIdx{:}) = 255;
end
out = img(stats(I).SubarrayIdx{:});
```

The result (using `imshow`):

[image: Output]